# maildrop and quota exceeded

Tags: postfix, quota, email

I implemented warning maildrop when quota exceeded. This worked correctly except for one detail.

The drawback is that sending mail notice is sent only time... I mean for example if the mailbox has been exceeded by more than 80 %, as I have configured , sends e- mail notification when exceeded, up there all right.

The problem is that if the mailbox is exceeded, even after 24 hrs no resend alert.

I noticed that when a mailbox exceeds the limit a file is created called **quotawarn** in the folder for the mailbox exceeded `/home/vmail/domain/mailbox/quotawarn`. If I delete that file, immediately the notice is sent. So that seems to come out there the topic.

I noticed in the documentation and understand that should function as says [here](http://www.courier-mta.org/maildrop.html), meaning that the warning limit is exceeded resend after 24 hrs, but this does not work.

Any idea ? thanks

Answer (score 1):

<sub>Put the solution by Sam Varshavchik from [cross-posted question in courier-maildrop mailing list](http://courier-mail-server.10983.n7.nabble.com/Maildrop-quotawarn-tp21494p21497.html)</sub>

The timestamp of the existing `quotawarn` file gets used to determine when the   24 hours since the last warning messages has elapsed.

Check the timestamp of the `quotawarn` file.

Additionally, in order for the warning to work, of course, all mail must be   delivered using `maildrop` or `deliverquota`. If you have something else that's   delivering mail, it is going to ignore `quotawarn`; that goes without saying.

---

In other words here the pseudocode to check this case

```
if there is incoming email
    if postfix deliver it via maildrop or deliverquota
        if quota threshold > 0
            if size of maildir > quota threshold
                if there is quotawarn file
                    if modified time of quotawarn + 86400 < now
                        write blank string to quotawarn file
                        put warning email into user mailbox
```